# Best way to recognise CURL calling

Tags: php, curl

What is the best way to recognise in script when it is called by CURL from another script on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a custom User-Agent header.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'your_custom_user_agent');
```

And in the script being called, you can recognize this internal request with

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'your_custom_user_agent') {
  // This is internal request!
}
```